# modbus messaging using Putty

Tags: putty, modbus, hyperterminal

I have a modbus metering device. How can I send modbus message using putty or hyper-terminal?
I just want to fetch those metering data.

Comment: Is your device MODBUS RTU or MODBUS ASCII? Depending on this you would have to send binary or ascii data. It's all in the description of the protocol. Using MODPOLL command line utility would be the easiest cross platform way to read metering data, which would save you from reading detailed protocol specification. If you need to access MODBUS devices from your application then there are many libraries which can be used for this purpose. You need to be more specific.

Comment: To simply read modbus data there's no need to use something as low level as putty. There are [tools that make modbus communication very easy](https://unserver.xyz/docs/v/latest/overview/) by providing an API on to of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@avra is correct: you want to make sure your device can support Modbus ASCII if you'd like to use a Terminal to attempt to poll Modbus registers.  However, even using Modbus ASCII protocol takes some Modbus experience, and even if you know the unit ID and registers you'd like to poll, you will need to calculate the CRC for the message.

Could you add some more detail on what you are hoping to accomplish?

Also, here's some light reading on Modbus RTU vs. ASCII: http://www.simplymodbus.ca/ASCII.htm

Good luck!